# Gradient Descent in Python from scratch produces wrong output

Tags: python, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I am trying to implement Gradient Descent in just random data to predict weight based on height and sex in python. Below is the dataset I have created using just random values and also the set of equations which I had derived to solve the problem. 
Here is the python code:

```
import numpy as np

def gradient(curr_x,curr_y,curr_z):
  x = np.array([[170, 0], [172, 1], [175, 1], [176, 0], [182, 0], [183, 1], [189, 1]])
  y = np.array([65, 63, 68, 69, 73, 76, 75])
  N=len(x)
  x_grad,y_grad,z_grad=0,0,0
  for i in range(7):
   x_grad = x_grad + (1/N)*((curr_x + curr_y * x[i,0] + curr_z * x[i,1])-y[i])
   y_grad = y_grad + (1/N)*((curr_x + curr_y * x[i,0] + curr_z * x[i,1])-y[i])*x[i,0]
   z_grad = z_grad + (1/N)*((curr_x + curr_y * x[i,0] + curr_z * x[i,1])-y[i])*x[i,1]


 new_x=curr_x-0.0001*x_grad
 new_y=curr_y-0.0001*y_grad
 new_z=curr_z-0.0001*z_grad

 return new_x,new_y,new_z

x,y,z=0,0,0
for i in range(800):
 x,y,z=gradient(x,y,z)

print(x,y,z)
```

My problem is that it is giving extremely wrong coefficients and intercept. When I predict the weight on [174,0],its coming negative.Can anybody help me here?

[Equations Derived](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxRqy.jpg)

[Raw Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyBGM.jpg)

Comment: Please format your code

Comment: Have you checked wheter a gradient descent implementation known to be correct (e.g. from a standard framework) produces proper results for your randomly created data?

Comment: Gradient descent convergence is very much dependent on the mixing parameter `alpha` value you choose. Did you try using a slightly larger/smaller alpha?

Comment: @IonicSolutions Sir I don't now tensorflow or any other ML library till now besides Scikit-Learn and I dont think they have GradientDescent available in them.

Comment: @Bazingaa Sir,though I altered the alpha(increased as well as decreased), the model prediction came out to be negative only.

Comment: You might want to work through a tutorial such as [this one](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/10/gradient-descent-with-python/). My concern would be that the data you generate cannot be approximated well.

Comment: @IonicSolutions thanks for your answer. One quick question how to do ordinary least squares with multiple linear regression?

Comment: You can use e. g. [`scipy.optimize.curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html).